# How do the guidelines for IBM MQ operating system (Linux) tuning have to be applied when running on Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, ibm-mq

we plan to run IBM MQ 9.0.5 inside a Linux Docker container and I'm not sure how the [IBM guidelines for Linux tuning](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q008550_.html) have to be applied in this case.
Those tuning steps include modification of several System V IPC kernel parameters (e.g. increasing the max. number of threads), increasing maximum number of file handles, processes etc.
Do those steps have to be applied to both the Docker host operating system and inside the container?

The IBM documentation for setting up MQ on Docker doesn't mention OS tuning at all, so I hope someone in here could help me?

Thanks in advance

David

Comment: MQ Client or MQ Server?

Comment: Server, I think the guidelines are only intended for a Server in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the (inofficial) response I got from an IBM Architect:

> I'm afraid I don't currently have a detailed list, but hopefully I can
>   point you in the right direction.
>
> Most of the settings apply to the kernel, and pass through to the
>   container automatically. Some of the settings are user-specific limits
>   (ulimits), which you can set in Docker using the "--ulimit" parameter
>   (see the Docker documentation).
>
> The networking settings can vary, based on your specific networking
>   environment (for example, if you're running on an overlay network).